# Google Cloud Platform random 404 on endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-logging

I have two apps deployed on google cloud. One exposes an api, that is consumed by the other.
But, sometimes, some of the request return a 404 http code. I cannot find a pattern to reproduce it yet. Any idea?

```
404 Cannot POST {link-to-api}
```

Comment: Use Stackdriver logging to see what is happening and which URLs are reporting 404.

Comment: That is how I tracked down the issue. But I am not tracing correctly, I will update this once I implement correct logging and tracing and find any information regarding this.